# Elasticsearch returns duplicate items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch for some part of my application and for some reason I get duplicate entries for some part of my users.

This is the search:

```
def newest_messages_for_user_by_elasticsearch(user)
  filter_conditions = {
      must: {term: {state: 'accepted'}},
      must_not: [
        {term: {"user_id" => user.id}}
      ]
    }

  self.search(
    query: { match_all: {} },
    filter: {bool: filter_conditions},
    sort: [
      {created_at: {order: :desc}}
    ]
  )
end
```

Can anyone tell me why it's returning duplicate items?

The two requests look like this:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/development_messages/message/_search?from=0&size=20 [status:200, request:0.002s, query:0.001s]
GET http://localhost:9200/development_messages/message/_search?from=20&size=20 [status:200, request:0.008s, query:0.002s]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, where is the method called from? A controller, I guess? Have you perchance added a `per_page: 20` or `size 20` around there?

Comment: Yes, I have pagination that changes the from parameter. It's just a simple link.